# Combining multiple javascript arrays into JSON using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a handful of javascript arrays that I have no control over as far as format or variable names. I need to combine 6 of them into a json array. I have it pretty close but can't seem to get it to iterate through both the list of variables as well as the count of array elements.

It is apparent to me that I do not remember how to handle variables or iteration in JS as well as  I used to and could really use some help.

**The software whose output I needs to parse generates something similar to the following:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var orderNum = 'OrderNum-485';
    var orderSubTotal ='130.8';
    var orderTotal  ='130.8';
    var numOfItems ='4';
    var items =new Array('Item Name 1','Item Name 2','Item Name 3','Item Name 4');
    var ids =new Array('item-id-1','item-id-2','item-id-3','item-id-4');
    var codes =new Array('ITEM-CODE-1','ITEM-CODE-2','ITEM-CODE-3','ITEM-CODE-4');
    var qtys =new Array('1','1','1','1');
    var price =new Array('12.95','46.7','1.2','69.95');
    var orderTax ='0';
    var orderShipping ='0';
    var appliedPromoIdList ='';
    var coupon ='';
    var storeId ='store_id';
    var activeShipPromotionCount ='';
    var itemImages =new Array('http://image_url','http://image_url','http://image_url','http://image_url');
</script>
```

**Where as the software that I need to pass data too expects the following (as an object, I managed to get it done using strings):**

```
[
         {
            "item_id":"item-id-1",
            "desc":"ITEM-CODE-1",
            "amount":"12.95",
            "quantity":"1",
            "name":"Item Name 1",
            "image": "http://image_url",
         {
            "item_id":"item-id-2",
            "desc":"ITEM-CODE-2",
            "amount":"46.7",
            "quantity":"1",
            "name":"Item Name 2",
            "image": "http://image_url",
     ]
```

**This is what I came up with:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var orderId = orderNum;
    var createItemObjects = function() {
    var keys = new Array ("item_id","desc","amount","quantity","name","image");
    var yahooKeys = new Array ("ids","codes","price","qtys","items","itemImages");
    var item,cartItems = [];
    var c = numOfItems;
    var k = yahooKeys.length;
    var i = 0;
    item = {};
    for (; i < k; i++) {
        var arrayName = yahooKeys[i].toString();
        var buffer = eval('' + arrayName);
        item[keys[i]] = buffer[0] //Ideally this should be the full range of 0-3 so that you can see each of the 4 items.
        document.write("<br />Loop: "+i);
        cartItems.push(item);
    }
    return cartItems;
```

**It generates correctly formatted data but 6 identical copies of the element indicated by buffer's hard coded value**

Comment: What now, do you need an object (in JS runtime) or a string (in JSON format)?

Comment: I believe I need an object. The Documentation is rather poor as this is a new feature. I had parsed it out as a JSON formatted string and it wouldn't take it. Their example code generates an Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of :

```
function createItemObjects(items, ids, codes, qtys, prices, images) {
    var check = items.length === ids.length && ids.length === codes.length &&
            qtys.length === codes.length && prices.length === images.length;
    if(!check) throw 'Arrays do not match';
    var results = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        results.push({
            item_id: ids[i],
            desc: codes[i],
            amount: parseFloat(prices[i]),
            name: items[i],
            quantity: qtys[i],
            image: images[i]
        })
    }
    return results;
}

var data = generate(items, ids, codes, qtys, prices, itemImages);
var json_string = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Comment: I've made the minor correction of switching prices back to price and correcting the function call to reflect the function name however I cannot get this to execute and monkeying with it has not helped. It hangs up trying to eval the length of items and comes up null. Trying to hardcoded it in causes it to then hang on ids. I'd paste it to js fiddle however they don't support document.write :/ http://pastie.org/private/ryyr3xiosmjhtwtq5andg

Comment: Never mind, I was calling the function incorrectly. I will continue to test and will return shortly.